# How to add documents in mongoose automatically based on date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add documents to mongoose model in database automatically daily,So that when ever new day begins a new record entry is added in database. Following are my model and schemas:

---

```
import { Schema, model, ObjectId } from "mongoose";

export type salahStatus = {
  fajr: boolean;
  dhuhr: boolean;
  asr: boolean;
  maghrib: boolean;
  isha: boolean;
};

export type salahRecordT = {
  date: Date;
} & salahStatus;

//Schema for recording Salahs of each day
const SalahRecordSchema = new Schema<salahRecordT>({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  fajr: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  dhuhr: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  asr: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  maghrib: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  isha: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

export interface UserT {
  _id: ObjectId;
  isVerified: boolean;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  salahRecord: salahRecordT[];-->need to add entry here daily
  googleToken: string;
}

//Main User Schema for recording user data
const UserSchema = new Schema<UserT>({
  isVerified: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
  },
  salahRecord: [SalahRecordSchema],
  googleToken: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const User = model<UserT>("users", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

---

I want that when ever new days begins. new document is added in db which is of salah record schema .For example following entry should be added each day

```
{
  date: Date,
  fajr: false
  dhuhr: false,
  asr: false,
  maghrib: false,
  isha: false
}
```

How can i achieve this in mongoose??

Comment: One solution would be to run a cron job daily on something like github actions, which will add that record to your MongoDB. You can also schedule / spin up a serverless function for the same.

Comment: @VikrantBhat I was hoping for achieving this through coding. Maybe mongdb / mongoose will have something like this which i don't know yet.

Comment: Cron job on a serverless function is something that you will have to code

Comment: Ok Thank you very much mate. will surely look into this.

Comment: MongoDB has [Scheduled Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/scheduled-triggers/) that can do this

Comment: @Reyno will look for the same in mongoose. Thank you.